# How come EF 7 is modifying a foreign key from x to y when I initially set it to be x?

Tags: entity-framework

I'm pulling an entity calling

```
var party = context.Parties.First(c => c.id = id)
```

On this entity I am adding a Customer to the navigation property Customers, which is initially empty, by creating a test customer like below:

```
var customer = new Customer()
            {
                **(PK, FK)** ParentSid = 52, 
                **(PK, FK)** ChildSid = 7,
                **(PK)** StartDate = relationship.StartDate,
                EndDate = relationship.EndDate,
            };

party.Customers.Add(customer);
context.SaveChanges();
```

When I call SaveChanges, it goes through it's DetectChanges routine and I can see in the log that it's detected the ChildSid changed from 7 to 52.
I can see the entity is correct in my locals window before SaveChanges is called so I know it's not being mapped incorrectly outside of EF.

```
dbug: 5/24/2023 19:37:27.491 CoreEventId.ReferenceChangeDetected[10805] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking) 
      The navigation 'Customer.ParentParty' for entity with key '{ParentSid: 52, ChildSid: 7, ApplicationStartDate: 05/24/2023 19:37:14}' was detected as changed.
dbug: 5/24/2023 19:37:27.497 CoreEventId.ForeignKeyChangeDetected[10803] (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking) 
      The foreign key property 'Customer.ChildSid' was detected as changed from '7' to '52' for entity with key '{ParentSid: 52, ChildSid: 52, ApplicationStartDate: 05/24/2023 19:37:14}'.
```

I've tried setting the navigation properties (parent and child) to the existing entities as well with their correct Sid's but SaveChanges is still changing the ChildSid.

It does work if I instead do

```
context.Customers.Add(customer); 
context.SaveChanges();
```

as opposed to

```
party.Customers.Add(customer)
```

Any pointers appreciated.